# Obstacles spawn too close to each other

Tags: python, pygame

I'm 99% done with programming my very first game. I'm really happy with how it's working, There's just 1 thing I want to change, but I don't know how to...

This is my code:

```
"""Program based on
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8n91btt5d8&list=PLNAPMEWWbHeegjsyN7_pSwXbYPrbyiYhh&index=2&t=1849s"""

import pygame
import sys
import time
import random

pygame.init()

width = 1400
height = 800

green = (0, 51, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

player_location = [width - 1350, height - 200]
player_size = [100, 200]

obsticle_size = [101, 101]
obsticle_location = [width - 100, height - 100]

obsticle_list = [obsticle_location]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

speed = 10

score = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 35)

run = True

def set_speed(score, speed): #speed up game as score gets higher
    if score < 5:
        speed = 10
    elif score < 10:
        speed = 15
    elif score < 20:
        speed = 20
    elif score < 35:
        speed = 25
    elif score < 50:
        speed = 30
    elif score < 75:
        speed = 35
    elif score < 100:
        speed = 40
    else:
        speed = 50
    return speed

def spawn_obsticle(obsticle_list): #spawn obsticle on floor, max 3 on screen
    delay = random.random()
    if len(obsticle_list) < 3 and delay < 0.0085:
        x_pos = width - 100
        y_pos = height - 100
        obsticle_list.append([x_pos, y_pos])

def spawn_obsticle_2(obsticle_list): #spawn obsticle in air, max 3 on screen
    delay = random.random()
    if len(obsticle_list) < 3 and delay < 0.0085:
        x_pos = width - 100
        y_pos = height - 300
        obsticle_list.append([x_pos, y_pos])

def draw_obsticle(obsticle_list): #create obsticle
    for obsticle_location in obsticle_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (obsticle_location[0], obsticle_location[1], obsticle_size[0], obsticle_size[1]))

def update_obsticle_positions(obsticle_list, score): #making obsticles move from right to left
    for idx, obsticle_location in enumerate(obsticle_list):
        if obsticle_location[0] >= 0 and obsticle_location[0] < width:
            obsticle_location[0] -= speed
        else:
            obsticle_list.pop(idx) #drop obsticles off screen, score +1 everytime this happenes
            score += 1
    return score

def collision_check(obsticle_list, player_location): #detect collision between player and obsticle, part 1
    for obsticle_location in obsticle_list:
        if detect_collision(obsticle_location, player_location):
            return True
        return False


def detect_collision(player_location, obsticle_location): #detect collision between player and obsticle, part 2
    p_x = player_location[0]
    p_y = player_location[1]

    p_width = player_size[0]
    p_height = player_size[1]

    o_x = obsticle_location[0]
    o_y = obsticle_location[1]

    o_width = obsticle_size[0]
    o_height = obsticle_size[1]

    if (o_x >= p_x and o_x < (p_x + p_width)) or (p_x >= o_x and p_x < (o_x + o_width)):
        if (o_y >= p_y and o_y < (p_y + p_height)) or (p_y >= o_y and p_y < (o_y + o_height)):
            return True
    return False

while run:

    clock.tick(FPS) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            sys.exit

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 

            x = player_location[0]   #x location of player
            y = player_location[1]   #y location of player

            p_width = player_size[0]    #starting player width
            p_height = player_size[1]    #starting player height


            if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #jump up by changing y location
                y -= 200

            player_location = [x,y] 

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_UP: #back to starting size and location when releasing key
               player_size = [100, 200]
               player_location = [50, 600]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() #stooping by switching width and heigt of player
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        p_width = player_size[1]
        p_height = player_size[0]
        y = 700

        player_size = [p_width,p_height]
        player_location = [x,y]

    screen.fill(black)

    spawn_obsticle(obsticle_list)
    spawn_obsticle_2(obsticle_list)
    score = update_obsticle_positions(obsticle_list, score)
    speed = set_speed(score, speed)

    text = "Score:" + str(score)            #making score appear on screen
    label = myFont.render(text, 1, yellow)
    screen.blit(label, (600, 250))

    if collision_check(obsticle_list, player_location): #ending game when there is contact between player and obsticle
        run = False

    draw_obsticle(obsticle_list)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (player_location[0], player_location[1], player_size[0], player_size[1]))

    pygame.display.update()
```

The game if very easy: you are the green block and you have to avoid the white blocks. For each block you avoid you get a point. The higher your score, the faster the obsticles move.

My problem is that sometimes a flying block and a block on the floor will spawn (almost) exactly on top of each other, making it impossible to dodge. (might not happen first time you run it, but if you run it a few times you'll definitely run into it)

How can I make it so they ALWAYS spawn with some distance between each other?

I just can't figure it out, and this would finish my first game. Thanks in advance
(Sorry for some bad English at some places. English isn't my mother tongue)

Comment: One strategy is to keep spawning at random locations, but then check if each object is too close to others.  If it is, then  discard it and try spawning again at a new location

Answer (score 0):

Increase the delay between each spawn. Change your spawn_obsticle function to this:

```
def spawn_obsticle(obsticle_list): #spawn obsticle on floor, max 3 on screen
    delay = random.random()
    if len(obsticle_list) < 3 and delay < 0.0185: # Used to be 0.0085
        x_pos = width - 100
        y_pos = height - 100
        obsticle_list.append([x_pos, y_pos])
```

Do this with both functions. I recommend putting both obstacle functions into one function, and halfing the change, so that two can't spawn on top of each other, and make an impossible barrier, such as something like this:

```
def spawn_obsticle(obstacle_list):
    delay = random.random()
    dist = random.choice([100, 300])
    if len(obstacle_list) < 6:
        x_pos = width-100
        y_pos = height-dist
        obsticle_list.append([x_pos, y_pos])
```

Comment: I figured putting both spawn_obstacle funtions together would solve the problem, but I'm still new to programming. If it wasn't for the video I mention in the beginnig I wouldn't have been able to come close tho this reslult . I honestly don't know how to put them together, as I'm working with 2 different y locations. I've tried some things, but none succesful

Comment: I edited it, hope this helps. Also, here's a good python tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm.

Comment: Thanks! It still happends occasionally, but already a lot less frequent. I'll try to figure it out myself from here on. The tutorial will help a lot, thanks :)